# JavaScript how to create inner function with function as an argument without imidietly invoking it?

Tags: javascript, function

I tried this but it's immediately invokes `addClass` after opening website  :

```
function onMouseOver(element, event) {
  element.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    event
  })
}

onMouseOver(startAnim, addClass(panelLeft, 'hidden-l'));
onMouseOver(startAnim, addClass(panelRight, 'hidden-r'));
```

Comment: Adding parenthesis after function will make it run immediately. You can try `addClass.bind(null, panelLeft, 'hidden-l')`. This will bind context and arguments and return a reference instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"[bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)" is what you are looking for and below you can see reference of how to use it.

```js
function innerFn(a, b) {
  console.log('Inner fn called with params ',a ,b)
}

function outerFn(c, fn) {
  console.log('Outer fn called with params ',c)
  
  fn()
}

outerFn('1', innerFn.bind(null, '2', '3'))
```

Comment: Most of the topics are answered. We should look for similar post as we know the real issue and can formulate better search query. Once we have such post, we should share its link in comments section until you have privilege to close yourself

Comment: Sure @Rajesh. Will take care of this. :)